# Traversing up, then back down the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I have a click event setup and inside its code block I'm storing the value of certain sibling elements. Right now if I wanted the text inside the `.title` span after clicking the `.play` button I have to work my way up two levels and back down to the `.title`.

I was wondering what would be a better way to access information from sibling elements wrapped in two or more parent divs?

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="number">01.</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="title">Track 1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="play">Play</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="number">02.</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="title">Track 2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
  $(".play").on("click", function() {
    var number = $(this).parent().parent().find(".number").text(),
    title      = $(this).parent().parent().find(".title").text();

    console.log(number + title);
  });
});
```

Comment: Just use `$(this).grandParent().find(".title").text()` to go up two parents efficiently

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think `grandParent()` even exists in the jQuery API.

Comment: many way to target required selector, but `.closest('tr').find('title')` functions are easy and good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `closest()` function.

```
var number = $(this).closest('tr').find(".number").text(),
title      = $(this).closest('tr').find(".title").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` to go back to a common parent

```
  var number = $(this).closest('tr').find(".number").text(),
   title      = $(this).closest('tr').find(".title").text();
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt17q3vp/)